# How to use BeautifulSoup to parse a table?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

This is a context-specific question regarding how to use BeautifulSoup to parse an html table in python2.7.

I would like to extract the html table [here](http://sloanconsortium.org/onlineprogram_listing?page=11&Institution=&field_op_delevery_mode_value_many_to_one%5B0%5D=100%25%20online) and place it in a tab-delim csv, and have tried playing around with BeautifulSoup.

Code for context:

```
proxies = {
    "http://": "198.204.231.235:3128",
}
site = "http://sloanconsortium.org/onlineprogram_listing?page=11&Institution=&field_op_delevery_mode_value_many_to_one[0]=100%25%20online"

r = requests.get(site, proxies=proxies)
print 'r: ', r
html_source = r.text
print 'src: ', html_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source)
```

Why doesn't this code get the 4th row?

```
soup.find('table','views-table cols-6').tr[4]
```

How would I print out all of the elements in the first row (not the header row)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey, someone might be able to give you a one liner, but the following should get you started

```
table = soup.find('table', class_='views-table cols-6')                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
for row in table.find_all('tr'):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    row_text = list()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    for item in row.find_all('td'):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        text = item.text.strip()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        row_text.append(text.encode('utf8'))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    print row_text
```

I believe your tr[4] is believed to be an attribute and not an index as you suppose.